# How to define a UITouch for an entire class

Tags: swift, user-interface, subclass, uitouch

Im creating a game and i am trying to create a joystick class. I declared the class as a UITouch class but I'm not quiet sure how to define the touch for the class without using a touches began, moved, or ended "METHOD" . Here is the class so far

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Joystick: UITouch {

let joystick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "joystick.png")

let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - self.joystick.position.x, dy: 
location.y - self.joystick.position.y)
let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
}
```

i get the error on the "let location = touch.locationInNode(self) I get an error that says "use of unresolved identifier "touch" "
why i want to define the angle for the whole class is because i have the joystick spawning bullets in the direction of a joystick's angle which requires me to call the joystick and the joy stick's angle in multiple methods. If any one could help I would be very grateful

Comment: Why you dont want to use touches began???. You have used touch as Set<UITouch> but you do not have this notification. You must subclass a SKSpriteNode  and use override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)

Comment: I don't want to use touches began because i have to call my joystick and bullet spawn location in different methods, how do i do that if my joystick is only defined in my touches began and touches moved methods @SimonePistecchia

Comment: Your Joystick class, must be: class Joystick: SKSpriteNode and inside this class, add  override func touchesBegan and put your code inside